# How to connect mongo replicaset on kubernetes cluster from another cluster pods

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes

I have a mongo db replicaset running on kubernetes cluster ( on AWS EKS ) , say cluster-1. This is running within VPC-1 having cidr 192.174.0.0/16.

I have another cluster in a separate VPC , say VPC-2, where I'll be running some applications on top of the mongo cluster. This VPC cidr range is 192.176.0.0/16. All VPC peering and security group ingress/egress rules are working fine and I am able to ping cluster nodes across the two VPCs.

I am using NodePort type service and StatefulSet for the mongo cluster :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: mongodb-service
  labels:
    name: mongodb
spec:
  selector:
    role: mongo
  type: NodePort
  ports:
  - port: 26017
    targetPort: 27017
    nodePort: 30017
```

Here are the nodes & pods in mongo cluster, cluster-1 :

```
ubuntu@ip-192-174-5-253:/st_config/kubeobj$ kubectl get nodes -o wide
NAME                                             STATUS   ROLES    AGE   VERSION              INTERNAL-IP       EXTERNAL-IP      OS-IMAGE         KERNEL-VERSION                  CONTAINER-RUNTIME
ip-192-174-187-133.ap-south-1.compute.internal   Ready    <none>   19h   v1.16.8-eks-e16311   192.174.187.133   13.232.195.39    Amazon Linux 2   4.14.181-140.257.amzn2.x86_64   docker://19.3.6
ip-192-174-23-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal    Ready    <none>   19h   v1.16.8-eks-e16311   192.174.23.229    13.234.111.139   Amazon Linux 2   4.14.181-140.257.amzn2.x86_64   docker://19.3.6
ubuntu@ip-192-174-5-253:/st_config/kubeobj$


ubuntu@ip-192-174-5-253:/st_config/kubeobj$ kubectl get pods -o wide
NAME       READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE   IP                NODE                                             NOMINATED NODE   READINESS GATES
mongod-0   1/1     Running   0          45m   192.174.8.10      ip-192-174-23-229.ap-south-1.compute.internal    <none>           <none>
mongod-1   1/1     Running   0          44m   192.174.133.136   ip-192-174-187-133.ap-south-1.compute.internal   <none>           <none>
ubuntu@ip-192-174-5-253:/st_config/kubeobj$
```

If I try to connect using a specific node address, OR both node addresses, kubernetes is perhaps load-balancing or rotating the connection in a round robin fashion:

```
ubuntu@ip-192-176-42-206:~$ mongo mongodb://192.174.23.229:30017
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://192.174.23.229:30017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.24
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
test_rs0:PRIMARY>

ubuntu@ip-192-176-42-206:~$ mongo mongodb://192.174.23.229:30017
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://192.174.23.229:30017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.24
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
test_rs0:SECONDARY>

ubuntu@ip-192-176-42-206:~$ mongo mongodb://192.174.23.229:30017,192.174.187.133:30017
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://192.174.23.229:30017,192.174.187.133:30017
MongoDB server version: 3.4.24
WARNING: shell and server versions do not match
test_rs0:PRIMARY>
```

I wish to leverage the replicaset features. So when I used the the connect string as - mongodb://192.174.23.229:30017,192.174.187.133:30017/?replicaSet=test_rs0 , it is actually getting the FQDNs of the pods which are not resolved from the node in cluster-2 nodes/pods in VPC-2.

```
ubuntu@ip-192-176-42-206:~$ mongo mongodb://192.174.23.229:30017,192.174.187.133:30017/?replicaSet=test_rs0
MongoDB shell version v3.6.3
connecting to: mongodb://192.174.23.229:30017,192.174.187.133:30017/?replicaSet=test_rs0
2020-06-23T15:59:07.407+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] Starting new replica set monitor for test_rs0/192.174.23.229:30017,192.174.187.133:30017
2020-06-23T15:59:07.409+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] Successfully connected to 192.174.23.229:30017 (1 connections now open to 192.174.23.229:30017 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-06-23T15:59:07.409+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] Successfully connected to 192.174.187.133:30017 (1 connections now open to 192.174.187.133:30017 with a 5 second timeout)
2020-06-23T15:59:07.410+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] changing hosts to test_rs0/mongod-0.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongod-1.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local:27017 from test_rs0/192.174.187.133:30017,192.174.23.229:30017
2020-06-23T15:59:07.415+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("mongod-1.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local") failed: Name or service not known
2020-06-23T15:59:07.415+0000 I NETWORK  [ReplicaSetMonitor-TaskExecutor-0] getaddrinfo("mongod-0.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local") failed: Name or service not known
2020-06-23T15:59:07.917+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("mongod-0.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local") failed: Name or service not known
2020-06-23T15:59:07.918+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] getaddrinfo("mongod-1.mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local") failed: Name or service not known
2020-06-23T15:59:07.918+0000 W NETWORK  [thread1] Unable to reach primary for set test_rs0
2020-06-23T15:59:07.918+0000 I NETWORK  [thread1] Cannot reach any nodes for set test_rs0. Please check network connectivity and the status of the set. This has happened for 1 checks in a row.
```

Do I need to have some additional DNS service so that the names get resolved in VPC-2 nodes ? What would be the best approach ?

Also how can I use connect string can be based on the service name eg. mongodb://mongodb-service.default.svc.cluster.local:/?replicaSet=test_rs0 from any node in VPC-2 ? It works from any pod in VPC-1. But I need to get this working from pods in cluster in VPC-2 so that I don't have to specify specific pod/node IP in connect string. All my kubernetes objects are in default namespace.

Really appreciate some help here.
**Please Note: I am NOT using helm **

Comment: @SureshVishnoi Could you please take a look and suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Kubernetes has coredns to connect to each pod.
If i didn't wrong you use StatefulSet deployment.

The best approch for connection each of your mongo cluster is use ClusterIP to communicate each other.

If you use same namespaces in mongo, you could connect use :
mongod-0.app_name:27017,mongod-1.app_name:27017

for each of your application

Note : app_name=mongod

Here some example :

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  namespace: mongo-cluster
  name: mongo
  labels:
    app: mongo
    name: mongo
spec:
  type: ClusterIP
  ports:
  - port: 27017
    targetPort: 27017
  selector:
    app: mongo
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  namespace: mongo-cluster
  name: mongo
spec:
  serviceName: "mongo"
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: mongo
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: mongo
    spec:
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 10
      containers:
      - name: mongo
        image: mongo
        command:
          - "numactl"
          - "--interleave=all"
          - "mongod"
          - "--replSet"
          - "MainSetRep"
          - "--bind_ip"
          - "0.0.0.0"
          - "--auth"
          - "--clusterAuthMode" 
          - "keyFile" 
          - "--keyFile" 
          - "/etc/secrets-volume/mongodb-keyfile" 
          - "--setParameter" 
          - "authenticationMechanisms=SCRAM-SHA-1"
        ports:
          - containerPort: 27017
        volumeMounts:
          - name: data
            mountPath: /data/db
        volumeMounts:
          - name: mongo-key
            mountPath: "/etc/secrets-volume"
            readOnly: true
      volumes:
      - name: mongo-key
        secret:
          defaultMode: 0400
          secretName: mongo-key
  volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: data
    spec:
      storageClassName: openebs-hostpath
      accessModes:
        - ReadWriteOnce
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 20G
```

Comment: I am looking at connecting to mongo instances in one cluster , from another cluster nodes/pods. The issue is that  the pod names like - "mongod-0.service_name"  or "mongod-0.service_name.<<namespace>>.svc.local"  is NOT resolved in the second cluster. The second cluster DNS has no idea how to translate them to IP addresses of the mongo cluster. Even if I use ClusterIP type service, this DNS translation issue is not going away.

Comment: Also while using ClusterIP type service, the load balancing would be done by kubernetes, which we perhaps do not want for mongo replicaset.

Comment: @Rajesh Okay, so you have 2 (or more) kubernetes cluster here? and you want to connect mongo to each kubernetes cluster

Comment: you can say, one cluster for DB and another for my apps. The app cluster nodes/pods should be able to connect to the DB pods. Btw, somehow I cannot get your user handle correctly. Not able to tag you correctly

Comment: Okay so need to expose your DB using external IP address. So it could contact each other. Kubernetes master has they own kube-dns. If you work with multiple kube cluster. U have to expose current services using external_IP